# Show translated value to user but save something else in database | Angularjs | Angular-Translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using Anguarjs and trying to translate with $translate

I have a dropdown list where I show translated options to the end-user. 
For example, English = "Red" and French = "Rouge", etc.

This has a problem, If a user who speaks French chooses "Rouge" and I want to query the DB for all the "RED" values, I will only get the ones that were chosen in English.

I want to show the translated values to the user when they choose something, but in DB always store a value that is not translated.
(Show something else, save something else [show: "Rouge"] [save: "Value1"])

JS Dropdown values=>

```
 personalityStyles:
            [
                $translate.instant('CONTACTS.FIERY_RED'),
                $translate.instant('CONTACTS.SUNSHINE_YELLOW'),
                $translate.instant('CONTACTS.COOL_BLUE'),
                $translate.instant('CONTACTS.EARTH_GREEN')
            ]
```

Translations (EN)=>

```
"CONTACTS.FIERY_RED": "Fiery Red (driver) (short-tempered, fast or irritable)",
"CONTACTS.SUNSHINE_YELLOW": "Sunshine Yellow (optimist) (optimistic, active and social)",
"CONTACTS.COOL_BLUE": "Cool Blue (analytic) (analytical, wise and quiet)",
"CONTACTS.EARTH_GREEN": "Earth Green (emphatic) (relaxed and peaceful)",
```

FR =>

```
"FIERY_RED": "Rouge ardent (conducteur) (coléreux, rapide ou irritable)",
"SUNSHINE_YELLOW": "Sunshine Yellow (optimiste) (optimiste, actif et social)",
"COOL_BLUE": "Cool Blue (analytique) (analytique, sage et silencieux)",
"EARTH_GREEN": "Terre verte (emphatique) (détendue et paisible)"
```

Now I don't want to save all this text, I just want to save RED or GREEN, etc. so that I have good data in my DB.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Code added above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sending and storing the translation key in the database, not the translated color. The translations themsleves are only a concern for the front end translation service. All other parts of your code should only deal with the translation keys.